# Node server not starting on AWS elastic beanstalk because of a bcrypt permission error - how to resolve this?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Similar to: [Beanstalk: Node.js deployment - node-gyp fails due to permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001516/beanstalk-node-js-deployment-node-gyp-fails-due-to-permission-denied)

My project already has a `.npmrc` file with contents `unsafe-perm=true` and I haven't had any issues with deployments and the node app running. All of a sudden today I deployed a new git commit and the node app won't start.

When I `cd` to `/var/app/current` and try to start the app using my standard `npm start` command, I get:

```
Error: /var/app/current/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

Checking the folder permissions I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx current]$ ls -la node_modules/
total 144
drwxr-xr-x 619 webapp webapp 20480 Oct 10 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 webapp webapp  4096 Oct 10 14:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 webapp webapp  4096 Oct 10 14:19 .bin
drwxr-xr-x   6 webapp webapp    91 Oct 10 14:19 @babel
// etc
```

When I change the folder permissions to belong to `ec2-user` by running the following:

`sudo chown -R $USER /var/app/current/node_modules`

then when I run `npm start` the app starts.

When I do a new `eb deploy my-environment` then everything defaults back to a broken state because (as I understand it) `/var/app/current` is symlinked to the new deploy.

Is anyone else **suddenly** facing this issue, or does anyone have any pointers?

NPM version:

```
$ npm -v
> 6.14.13
```

Node version:

```
$ node -v
> v14.17.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add platform hooks that allow the `webapp` user to sudo install the dependency tree. See this accepted answer:

[Sharp JS Dependency breaks Express Server on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179711/sharp-js-dependency-breaks-express-server-on-elastic-beanstalk#)